# how to return some default value for items in 'where' clause which are not matching(not existing) in database table column

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a database table `flight`

```
pkid       from_city            to_city
1         Melbourne            BuenosAires
2         Budapest             Tokyo
3         Praslin              Anchorage
```

Then I have a list/tuple of some random to_cities `['Paris','Tokyo','Madrid','Anchorage','im_not_on_earth']`

Now using sqlalchemy metadata I want a query which would return a `pkid` for a matching `to_city` in the given list  if exists or else return some default value say `0` if doesn't exist

So basically my output should give me surely some integer for every city where I can map each integer in my output to some city in the given input

Any example outputs as follows will work for me -

```
{'Paris':0, 'Tokyo': 2, 'Madrid': 0, 'Anchorage': 3, 'im_not_on_earth': 0}
```

or simply......  `[0,2,0,3,0]`

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do this? I thought I could achieve this by using coalesce. But that works only if the values in where clause exists in db table. Not sure if my understanding of coalesce is right.

**EDIT:**
** *I don't want to iterate using for loop and query for each element in the given input* **

Comment: In this case, it is best handled at the application level where you need to check the count of results to your query. If there are no results, then instead of returning a value from your database, you just return 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `apply()` and define your own function, for example:

```
def get_id(x):

    find = flight[flight['to_city']==x]['pkid'].values
    match = find[0] if list(find) else 0
    return match

dict(zip(to_cities, pd.Series(to_cities).apply(get_id).values))
```

Yields:

```
{'Paris': 0, 'Tokyo': 2, 'Madrid': 0, 'Anchorage': 3, 'im_not_on_earth': 0}
```

Comment: flight is not a dataframe. flight is a database table

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do an outer join between your provided list of cities and the to_city column in the flight table. Given that the database has no knowledge of your list of provided cities you will have to do this join in application code with a loop. In your example code you also have each to_city appearing in only one database row and thus mapping to only one pkid. I assume that it would be possible for multiple different from_cities to have flights going to the same to_city and thus you will need to have each to_city mapping to a list of pkids rather than a single value. A to_city with no flights going to it will therefore be represented by an empty list rather than a 0.

You can retrieve the list of matching cities with a single database query but you will need a loop to do the outer join with your provided list of to_cities. The following code should achieve what you want. As you have not provided your sqlalchemy code I have assumed you are using the ORM with the Declarative system to define your table.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Flight(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'flight'

    pkid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    from_city = Column(String)
    to_city = Column(String)

to_cities = ['Paris','Tokyo','Madrid','Anchorage','im_not_on_earth']
query_result = session.query(Flight.to_city, Flight.pkid).filter(Flight.to_city.in_(to_cities)).all()
matching_cities = defaultdict(list)
for city, pkid in query_result:
    matching_cities[city] += [pkid]
result = {city: matching_cities.get(city, []) for city in to_cities}
```

It would be worth thinking about your database design given that you are having to do an outer join in application code. The database would be a far more efficient place to carry this out. If you had a separate table of all city names with a foreign key relationship to the flight table then you could achieve what you want in a single query by performing an outer join between the city and flight tables within your query.